# PL/Python with Anaconda

Tags: python, postgresql, anaconda, plpython

I've got Anaconda installed on a Ubuntu and would like to use some of it's modules in PL/Python. However, every time I call scipy, it errors with *ImportError: No module* named scipy.stats.

How do I get the Anaconda to work with PL/Python?

UPDATED: Below is the code & the error

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hdi_bars(
    numerator integer,
    denominator integer)
  RETURNS SETOF double precision[] AS
$BODY$

from scipy.stats import beta
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import beta
import numpy as np

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpythonu VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION hdi_bars(integer, integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;

ERROR:
ERROR:  ImportError: No module named scipy.stats
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "hdi_bars", line 5, in 
    from scipy.stats import beta
PL/Python function "hdi_bars"

********** Error **********

ERROR: ImportError: No module named scipy.stats
SQL state: XX000
Context: Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "hdi_bars", line 5, in 
    from scipy.stats import beta
PL/Python function "hdi_bars"

Comment: please add a short example of the code you are using and the full error traceback.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated my post to include some of the code and the error I get back from PostgreSQL.

Comment: Are you sure you're running anaconda and not the system python when you do this?  (From your script you can do `import sys; print(sys.executable)` to verify.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [Postgres installation/configuration docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/install-procedure.html), there is an environment variable `PYTHON` which can be set to the full path of the executable for Python that you want. Otherwise, the default `--with-python` behavior will look for the system Python, most likely at `/usr/bin/python` or similar standard location for other operating systems.

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921664/how-to-change-python-version-used-by-plpython-on-mac-osx) seems to confirm that to alter it, you need to rebuild Postgres from source.